# PDF file when opening in Android Nougat is showing blank screen

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-pdf-api

I am creating a PDF file and saving it in local storage. When trying to open it, it is working perfect in all devices except in Android N. I am able to open PDF file in Android N using FileProvider, but it is displaying as blank.

This is my URI

```
content://com.products.provider/external_storage_root/Android/data/com.products/in_17052017_170502_1_1001.pdf
```

This is my code

```
Uri path;

File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                + "Android" + "/" + "data" + "/" + "com.products" + "/" + file);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.products.provider", pdfFile);
        } else {
            path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        }

        // Setting the intent for pdf reader
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        try {
            startActivity(pdfIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can't read pdf file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: It might be in zoomed state. Did you try to zoom out and see? Are you able to see page count?

Comment: It isn't in zoomed state. Only file name is displaying on top, rest of the screen is blank. When opened the same file through explorer, I can see the data.

Comment: May I know what app you are using to view the PDF file? 
and few more troubleshooting questions :)
1. Did you try to open any other PDF file?
2. Did you try any other PDF app?

Comment: when tried with Drive PDF Viewer and Google PDF Viwer, PDF is blank . When tried with Adobe Acrobat Reader, i got message as "This file cannot be accessed. Check the location and try again"

Comment: Try to open an input stream for the uri yourself. And read from it a bit.

Comment: Add a pdfFile.exists() check before you make that intent.

Comment: @greenapps PdfFile exists. It is opening file but it is blank.

Comment: And the input stream? Please react serious to suggestions.

Comment: Problem is not only on Nougat. It lies from Lollipop 5.1 (API 22) to Nougat 7.1.1 (API 25). By the way, haven't checked this issue on Oreo.

Answer (score 45):

The problem is with how you are setting the flags on the intent

```
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Instead, try this:

```
pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Comment: This was it for me! Thanks.

Comment: OH.MY.GOD. I was getting really annoyed with this. Solved.

Comment: YOU DA MAN!!! several days wasted with this issue. Your solution worked

Answer (score 7):

Grzegorz Matyszczak's solution worked for my case. I had a very similar setup to Sabya Sachi. More specifically this line allowed me to see the PDF file (URI from FileProvider.getURIForFile call):

```
pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

More info on `grantUriPermissions` [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#gprmns), under `android:grantUriPermissions` section.

Answer (score 4):

As I can see that you have used `FileProvider` for Nougat.
You have to add a FileProvider tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
</provider>
```

A FileProvider can only generate a content URI for files in directories that you specify beforehand.To link this file to the FileProvider, add a  element as a child of the  element that defines the FileProvider.

```
<provider
           android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

You must specify a child element of  for each directory that contains files for which you want content URIs. You can add them to a new file called `res/xml/file_paths.xml`. For example ,these XML elements specify two directories:

```
<paths  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
    <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>
</paths>
```

->you have to set your PDF directory path in `file_paths.xml`

For more detail refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

Comment: `<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths> `  But this is also not working

Comment: No, I am not getting anything in log

Comment: what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 25, I can't decrease it as I am using some library which is not compatible with 23

Comment: try to Clean your project once.

Comment: I have tried everything, but nothing works. Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace FileProvider class with MyFileProvider class:

`path = MyFileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.products.provider", pdfFile);`

where `MyFileProvider` should be a generic class which extends `FileProvider`:

```
public class MyFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

2. Modify AndroidManifest by setting your MyFileProvider class location to `android:name` attribute in your `provider` section:

```xml
android:name=".utils.MyFileProvider"
```