# Pdf files store in internal storage cannot be viewed only in Nougat but works in lower than Nougat

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, android-7.0-nougat

i have one pdf file in internal storage of my device using below code to view pdf this code is working in all version of android except nougat.

Class to generate Pdf is as follows :

```
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filepath);
        if(!dir.exists()) {

            dir.mkdir();
        }
        filename = "O"+pref.getCurrentOdrerId()+".pdf";
        System.out.println("filename: "+filename);
        pdfFile = new File(dir.getAbsoluteFile()+"/"+filename);

        Uri uri;
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= Constants.ANDROID_NOUGAT) {
            //uri = Uri.parse(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    new File(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        else{
            uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.showInvoicePdf);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.loadUrl(uri.toString());//String.valueOf(new File(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please remove all irrelevant code. Five code lines would have been enough to demonstrate your problem. Further you did not tell what your problem is and there is no question. Please dont just dump code here. Behave.

Comment: @greenapps It will be very helpful if you can help me in solving the problem . Hope the edit clears my question. Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: It would be very helpfull if you removed all irrelevant code first.

Comment: i removed all the irrelevant code

Comment: You did not mention that you are trying to load a pdf file in a WebView. A WebView cannot display a pdf file.

Comment: If there is already a pdf file in a dir then calling mkdir does not make sense. Isnt it?

Comment: Besides of that i see no reason to use a file provider for nougat. That would only be needed if you used an external app to display the pdf. Well... you have to use an external app now, anyhow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016169/

Comment: @greenapps Thanks finally solved using GitHub.PdfViewer library.

Comment: PLease refer below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947591/open-a-pdf-file-inside-a-webview/6040247#6040247